# Central SQL Server development database server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

We are in the process of rethinking our development environment. At the moment, we all have Elitebook notebooks which are not as fast as we'd like. We're thinking of virtualizing our development environment to a central VM server.

Our developers work in Visual Studio and use SQL Server as a database. We also have a few SharePoint developers who need a 64bit Win2k8 machine for SharePoint 2010. These are already virtual machines with their own local SQL Server installation.

Every developer's machine or VM has SQL Server installed. This requires resources from all boxes, and is challenging when working with a team on a project. Therefore we're looking into the possibility of centralizing the resources into a single DB server. That box would have to run multiple SQL Server instances (each Sharepoint developer needs a separate one to begin with). We also have the need for an older SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2000 installation for backwards compatibility. Besides the SQL Server box, the plan consists of a VM session for each developer with the development tools installed. So a developer could just RDP into the development environment, have his own image and make use of the centralized DB server. Test servers will also be virtualized in the same environment.

I'm looking for some tips and best practices on this matter. For instance:

- What's the number of SQL Server instances a normal box can take? And if we upscale virtualized cores / memory; is that enough to add new instances? I don't expect heavy usage in dev.
- What's the downside on centralizing the SQL Server instances as opposed to keeping a local instance on every development box?
- How should this be integrated in a DTAP strategy?

Comment: I can't help but wonder what are you doing with the database that requires a separate instance for each dev. Why not give each dev it's own database within a single instance?

Comment: That's the way SharePoint works, it needs multiple databases and you can't host multiple SharePoint instances in one SQL instance. Mainly because it creates a SharePoint_Config database which cannot be renamed, so a second instance will connect to the existing one instead of creating a new one (which is not what we want).

Comment: @Jasper, What did you end up doing? I'm having the same dilemma right now, but not sure if it's good to let everyone work on same database set or create instances? In our case there is like 8 databases that we work on at the same time

Comment: Well, with current day development of SharePoint apps, this question has become a lot simpler to answer. Just give your devs a developer site and use the local environment for provider hosted apps and services. If really needed, we use Azure for per-dev development machines (VM).

Answer (score 2):

Just some thoughts:

The number of instances is hardware dependent; I'm not sure if there's a mathematical formula to help calculate how many instances you can run on a VMbox, but it sounds like you're going to need a beast of a machine to run multiple instances per developer PLUS development tools (I can barely get SSMS and Visual Studio to play nice on my laptop).  Better hardware = more cost.

Developing on a terminal system may have some advantages, but I can think of a few disadvantages as well:

- network latency.  If your developers work remotely at all, they'll
  need a fast internet connection in order to do anything.  If the dev
  environments stay on their laptops, they could work disconnected.
- instance interdependence.  Although SQL Server instances are 
  completely seperate, sometimes you gotta reboot the server.  You'll
  need to coordinate that with all of your developers (may not be a big
  deal if there's only a handful of you).
- redundancy/maintenance.  If one developer's machine is down, you 
  lose a person-day (is that even a word?) of productivity; if the 
  server goes down, your company is paying for a holiday for everyone
  :)

Have you priced out what it would cost to upgrade your individual workstations so that you could compare costs on building out a centralized infrastructure?

Again, these are just some challenges that I think you should consider; there are probably ways to offset them, but they may factor in to your decision.

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks for your insights. Of course working completely remote comes with some challenges, but we believe there is a good future in that approach. Though we might have to choose for some sort of hybrid, that would be an option too. Just trying to figure things out right now. As for the instances: a seperate one is only required per SharePoint developer. And we could choose to keep those on the dev machines. The other (asp.net) devs could collaborate in a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would centralize the database servers as best as you can.  Having all the dev's work off of centralized database instances should make migrating changes between environments **MUCH** easier.  That alone is worth the effort.

For the SharePoint development environment, I'd highly recommend investing in a few books to make sure you go down the right path.  You should be able to have all the dev's working off the same development instances for that too.  Here is a good book on the subject, I'm sure there are others: [SharePoint 2010 Development](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/setting-your-sharepoint-2010-development-environment)

As far as making the developer machines VM's too, I would seek the input of the development staff first and foremost and seriously consider Stuart's pros & cons.

Comment: Chris, thanks for your comment. I already have enough books on SharePoint and recommended development hardware, but our company is choosing the centralize & cloud approach path and asked me to see what's possible there. I must admit that I do like the idea of having big powerfull servers available instead of a single notebook which gets slower every month and should be replaced every other year to keep everything going smoothly. But as I replied to Stuart as well: a hybrid aproach might be the best for now, I'm just not entirely sure yet. Thanks again for your comment!